# node.js Number.prototype isn't behaving as expected

Tags: prototypejs, typeerror, primitive-types

I'm trying to do a little math library to facilitate my app, this however is throwing an off error.

> TypeError: Object 25 has no method 'permutation'

```
function permutate(p) {
    var states = new Number(p.length)
    chat( states.permutation(states) )
}

Number.prototype.factorial = function() { 
    for(var i = 2; i <= this; i++)
        n*=i 
    return n
}
Number.prototype.permutation = function(r) { 
    return (this.factorial() / (this-r).factorial())
}
```

in addition to hopefully fixing  my code, I'm really curious why the objects type is being interpreted as a number primitive? (or whatever is really going on here)

Comment: not sure what your code is supposed to be doing, but it runs. http://jsfiddle.net/u2svx/2/

Comment: it doesn't run in node.js

Comment: What I posted doesn't run if you copy it to your code?

Comment: "console.log( states.permutation(states) )
                        ^
TypeError: Object 3 has no method 'permutation'..."

Comment: im trying to require() these prototypes, could that have something to do with it?

Comment: You have to run them before you can use them. You can put the whole thing in a function and do `require(name)()`

Comment: not sure what you mean?
I have require('util.js'), currently. how do i make the permutation and factorial prototypes available in the other file?